# ASP.NET httpconfiguration mappings with both route and querystring params

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

first time poster and I've a problem that, to me, this feels a bit like a 101 question but I've been having trouble getting these legacy mappings to correctly route. At the moment, I have one controller (separate c# library) and two actions to map to.

```
public class FindStuffController : ApiController
{
        [HttpGet()]
        public IEnumerable<StuffResource> FindStuffByDates(String emailAddress, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            //do stuff...
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public StuffResource FindStuffById(String emailAddress, String stuffId)
        {
            //do stuff...
        }
}
```

In the WebApiConfig of the WebApi project, I have the following mappings:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
     config.Filters.Add(new BasicTokenAuthorizationFilter());
     config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingFilter());

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "FindStuffBetweenDates",
                routeTemplate: "stuff/{emailAddress}",
                defaults: new { controller = "FindStuff", action = "FindStuffByDates" }
            );

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "FindStuffById",
                routeTemplate: "stuff/{emailAddress}/{stuffId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "FindStuff", action = "FindStuffById" }
            );
}
```

For each endpoint respectively, the expected uri for backwards compatibility reasons is expected to be... 
      "~/stuff/{emailAddress}?start={start}&end={end}"
... and ...
      "~/stuff/{emailAddress}/{stuffId}"

However, I am only able connect to the "FindStuffById" in my testing. Any and all attempts to connect to "FindStuffBetweenDates" ends in a 404 error. As a note, If I change the mapping so that all of the action parameters are either in the route or the querystring, then the action gets mapped correctly. This issue only seems to be if I have parameters in both.

Last I was aware, it was allowable to have action parameters in both the routing and query string but now I'm not 100% sure what is going on. I've even removed the DateTime params from the action and tried to route it with no more success. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. I'm guessing that either your query string is malformed, or you didn't provide all the values (both for start and end). Web API requires all the parameters to be satisfied for the action to match.

So the actual url should look like (for the case of string parameter)

```
/stuff/a@b?start=5&end=7
```

Also consider writing the controller code using attribute routing, it will be a lot cleaner and simpler to track. Here is an example

```
public class FindStuffController : ApiController
{
    [Route("stuff/{emailAddress}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string FindStuffByDates(string emailAddress, string start, string end)
    {
        return "start = " + start + " end = " + end;
    }

    [Route("stuff/{emailAddress}/{stuffId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public object FindStuffById(string emailAddress, string stuffId)
    {
        return "byId = " + stuffId;
    }
}
```

And the startup code will just look like:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // configure the rest of the services/formatters

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

If you want the parameters to be optional mark them as such in the method signature

```
    [Route("stuff/{emailAddress}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string FindStuffByDates(string emailAddress, string start = null, string end = null)
    {
        return "start = " + start + " end = " + end;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay but I think I figured out what was up. I think IIS was catching the routes and was routing them as if they were page routes, not http routes.

Basically, it believed everything had to end with a "/" so...

```
  ~/stuff/{emailAddress}?start={start}&end={end}
```

... was unacceptable but...

```
 ~/stuff/{emailAddress}/?start={start}&end={end}
```

... worked just fine.

I added in...

```
<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"
           preCondition="" />
```

to the system.webserver/modules section of the project web config and it seems to have resolved that issue. Probably not the most elegant of ways to do it but at least it works.

However, to Yishai's point, I do realize that mapping implicitly like this is cause for pain. I was a proponent of explicitly routing on the method. However, I lost that debate in planning.

Comment: Note that in MVC 6 (which is the next version of Web API) we are not going to support (for APIs) any of this conventional routing. So if you guys ever plan to upgrade, start the attribute routes way.